# List structure - checking for sublist

Tags: c, pointers, sublist

As i'm new to C programming, I'll be posting entire (not long code). Tasks i've been given are to implement insertion of an element inside list, while list stays in order, to print it, and then to check if one list is sublist of another. 
Although my *insert* and *print* methods work, I get a bunch of warnings:
*warning: passing argument 1 of 'Insert' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]|*. How can fix my code in order to remove these warnings?

Also, logically, I think that Contains method is OK, so why doesn't it work? It does work when comparing two lists of single element.

Code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct Book{
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float earnings;
} Book;

struct Node{
    struct Book data;
    struct Node* next;
};

void Insert(struct Node** list, struct Book k)
{
    struct Node* previous;
    struct Node* current;
    struct Node* newNode;

    newNode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    newNode->data = k;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(*list==NULL)
    {
        *list = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        current = *list;
        previous = NULL;

        while((current!=NULL) && current->data.earnings<k.earnings){
            previous = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
        if(current == NULL)
            previous->next = newNode;
        else
        {
            if(previous == NULL)
            {
                newNode->next = (*list);
                *list = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                previous->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = current;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Print(struct Node** list){
    if((*list)==NULL){
       printf("List is empty.");
       return;
    }
    printf("\nList looks like this:\n");
    while(*list!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n",(*list)->data.id);
        printf("%s\n",(*list)->data.name);
        printf("%f\n",(*list)->data.earnings);
        *list = (*list)->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int Contains(struct Node** l1, struct Node** l2){
    while((*l2)!=NULL)
    {
        while((*l1)!=NULL)
        {
            if((*l1)->data.id==(*l2)->data.id && (*l1)->data.name==(*l2)->data.name)
                return 1;

            *l1 = (*l1)->next;
        }
        *l2 = (*l2)->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct Book book = {5,"War and peace",100.50};
    struct Node** n = NULL;
    struct Book book1 = {6,"Anna Karenina",20.5};
    struct Book book2 = {7,"Master and Margarita", 150.60};
    struct Node** n1 = NULL;
    struct Book book3 = {6,"Anna Karenina",20.5};


    Insert(&n,book);
    Insert(&n,book1);
    Insert(&n,book2);
    Print(&n);
    Insert(&n1,book3);

    printf("\nDoes list2 contains list1? YES - 1, NO - 0 : %d",Contains(&n1,&n));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `struct Node** n = NULL;` with `struct Node* n = NULL;` and do the same for n1

what you're currently doing actully pass `struct Node*** list` and thats why you get the warnings

for the problem with `Contains`, first to compare strings use `strcmp` what you did just checked the pointers,
second after your first loop on `l1` you end up with `l1==NULL` so it won't get into the while after the first time

```
int Contains(struct Node** l1, struct Node** l2)
{
    struct Node* tmp;

    while ((*l2) != NULL)
    {
        tmp = *l1;
        while (tmp != NULL)
        {
            if(tmp->data.id==(*l2)->data.id &&
                strcmp(tmp->data.name, (*l2)->data.name) == 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        *l2 = (*l2)->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed that, and in Contains and in Print method, so this solves my problem with warnings. The problem with sublist still remains...

Comment: This does it, thank you. Also, @M Oehm pointed out that i do not need those extra pointers in Contains method, and with them moved, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the address of `n` to `Insert`. `n` is a pointer to pointer to node, `struct Node **`, so `&n` is a pointer to pointer to pointer to node, `struct Node ***`.

The solution is to make `n` and `n1` pointers to nodes:

```
struct Node* n = NULL;

Insert(&n, book);
```

The logic for the insertion code is that `n` is the head of a linked list. When `n` is `NULL`, the list is empty. When you insert nodes, you must be able to update the head pointer, so that it the value of `n` in `main` changes. One way to do this is to pass a pointer to the head and update it ba dereferencing tha pointer.

Your `Contains` and `Print` functions don't change the lists, so it is sufficient to pass pointers to nodes. That will also make your code look simpler, because you don't need the `(*p)`syntax everywhere.

The `contains` function has two errors: First, you cannot compare C strings with `==`. C strings are char arrays; if you want to compare them, you must compare their contents. The standard function `strcmp` from `<strings.h>` does this.

Secondly, you have a nested loop of two linked-list traversals. You can use the original node variable to traverse the outer loop, but you must use an additional node pointer for the inner loop and reset it before traversing the list.

It is also not clear what "contains" means. In the current (intended)  implementation, it means: Is there any common book in the two lists? A more useful function would ask the question: Is a certain book in the list?

Here's a modified variant of `Contains`

```
int Contains(struct Node *l1, struct Node *l2)
{
    while (l2 != NULL) {
        struct Node *p = l1;

        while (p != NULL) {
            if (p->data.id == l2->data.id 
            && strcmp(p->data.name, l2->data.name) == 0)
                return 1;

            p = p->next;
        }

        l2 = l2->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which you can call like this:

```
int c = Contains(n1, n);
```

Comment: Thank you very much as well. It's a shame two answers cannot be accepted... Explanation on passing pointers is very helpful, I'll make sure your effort is paid off when I get enough reps :D

Comment: @NemanjaZoríć: Don't worry too much about that. I'm glad you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please study the following. The main idea is that we make better use of functions, and do not pass around pointer-to-pointer references to list; our `Insert` function returns the new list. We also take advantage of recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct Book {
    int id;
    char name[50];
    float earnings;
} Book;

typedef struct Node{
    Book data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node, *List;

#define Empty ((List) NULL)

List NewNode(struct Book data, List next)
{
    List newNode = (Node *) malloc(sizeof *newNode);
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = next;
    return newNode;
}

List Insert(List list, struct Book book)
{
    if (list == Empty) {
        return NewNode(book, Empty);
    } else if (list->data.earnings < book.earnings) {
        return NewNode(book, list);
    } else {
        /* Rewrite the rest of the list by inserting into it,
           then patch the front node to point to the rewritten list. */
        List subList = Insert(list->next, book);
        list->next = subList;
        return list;
    }
}

void PrintOne(List list)
{
    printf("%d\n", list->data.id);
    printf("%s\n", list->data.name);
    printf("%f\n" ,list->data.earnings);
}

void Print(List list)
{
    if (list == Empty) {
       puts("List is empty.");
    } else {
        puts("List looks like this:");
        for (; list != Empty; list = list->next)
            PrintOne(list);
    }
}

int IsTailOf(List leftList, List rightList)
{
    if (leftList == rightList)
        return 1; /* Every list is its own tail */
    else if (rightList == Empty)
        return 1; /* The empty list is the tail of all lists, incl. itself */
    else if (leftList == Empty)
        return 0; /* Nonempty right cannot be tail of empty left */
    else
        return IsTailOf(leftList->next, rightList); /* Tail of my rest is my tail */
}


int main()
{
    Book book0 = {5,"War and peace",100.50};
    Book book1 = {6,"Anna Karenina",20.5};
    Book book2 = {7,"Master and Margarita", 150.60};
    Book book3 = {6,"Anna Karenina",20.5};

    List n0, n1, n2;

    List list = Empty;

    n0 = list = Insert(list, book0);
    list = Insert(list, book1);
    n1 = list = Insert(list, book2);
    Print(n0);
    n1 = list = Insert(list, book3);

    printf("List pointers: list == %p, n0 == %p, n1 == %p, n2 == %p\n",
           (void *) list, (void *) n0, (void *) n1, (void *) n2);

    printf("Does list contain n0? YES - 1, NO - 0 : %d\n",
           IsTailOf(list, n0));

    printf("Does n1 contain list? YES - 1, NO - 0 : %d\n",
           IsTailOf(n1, list));

    printf("Does n0 contain list? YES - 1, NO - 0 : %d\n",
           IsTailOf(n0, list));

    return 0;
}
```

The sublist function `IsTailOf` works strictly with the node pointers, based on a possible interpretation of what "sublist" means. It detects whether the right list is physically a piece of the left list (or the whole thing).

If you want to calculate whether a given list has a tail which is identical to another list, that is different. A simple approach for this which leads to easy-to-write (and read) code is to first implement an equivalence test function compares two lists. Then this test can be tried repeatedly:

```
#include <string.h> /* for strcmp */

int EqualBooks(Book left, Book right)
{
    return left.id == right.id && strcmp(left.name, right.name) == 0;
}

int EqualLists(List left, List right)
{
    /* Different style here from IsTailOf, just for variety:
       no "if else", just "if and return" */

    if (left == right)
        return 1; /* They are the same object! */

    if (left == Empty || right == Empty)
        return 0; /* Empty is not equal to nonempty */

    if (!EqualBooks(left->data, right->data))
        return 0; /* Equal lists must be equal in the first item */

    /* Equal lists must have equal remainders, not only first items */
    return EqualLists(left->next, right->next);
}
```

A simply implemented sublist test (let's call it a "suffix" test) then looks something like:

```
int IsSuffixOf(List left, List right)
{
    if (EqualLists(left, right))
        return 1; /* a full match implies suffix relationship */

    if (left == Empty)
        return 0; /* Nonempty cannot be a suffix of empty */

    return IsSuffixOf(left->next, right);
}
```

Trivial tail recursion is easily turned into iteration. Let's take `IsSuffixOf`. First, re replace the tail call by an assignment to the `left` and `right` variables, and add a backwards `goto`:

```
int IsSuffixOf(List left, List right)
{
tail:
    if (EqualLists(left, right))
        return 1; /* a full match implies suffix relationship */

    if (left == Empty)
        return 0; /* Nonempty cannot be a suffix of empty */

    left = left->next;
    goto tail;
}
```

Now it is iterative; we just eliminate the `goto` by rewriting to a `for` loop:

```
int IsSuffixOf(List left, List right)
{
    for (;; left = left->next) {
        if (EqualLists(left, right))
            return 1; /* a full match implies suffix relationship */

        if (left == Empty)
            return 0; /* Nonempty cannot be a suffix of empty */
     }
}
```